# Bling Accounting - Badge summaries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stackexchange

A question was [raised in chat (hi @malachi)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19035139#19035139) about how you can count the number of badges of a given metal (bronze, silver, gold). This can be hard to do because the medal details are not stored in the SEDE tables. Together with Malachi, we came up with this [Users and Badges](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/257582/users-and-badges) query:

```
-- Find and classify all badge awards for people
-- display summary of gold/silver/bronze awards, and also
-- for tag, or regular badges.
-- Results can be large, so limit it by users with a configurable
-- minimum number of badges.

with BadgeClass as (

  -- For all regular badges, link in the metal
  -- this has to be done manually as there is no reference
  -- in the database for it.

  -- tag badges all have lower-case names, other badges start with an upper-case.

  select distinct
         Name,
         case when LOWER(Name) = Name
                   then 'Tag'
              when Name in ('Socratic', 'Stellar Question', 'Great Question', 
                            'Famous Question', 'Illuminator', 'Great Answer', 
                            'Populist', 'Reversal', 'Unsung Hero', 'Fanatic', 
                            'Legendary', 'Marshal', 'Constable', 'Sheriff', 
                            'Steward', 'Copy Editor', 'Electorate', 'Publicist' )
                   then 'Gold'
              when Name in ('Inquisitive', 'Favorite Question', 'Good Question', 
                            'Notable Question', 'Enlightened', 'Refiner', 'Generalist', 
                            'Guru', 'Good Answer', 'Necromancer', 'Tenacious', 
                            'Constituent', 'Pundit', 'Enthusiast', 'Epic', 'Beta', 
                            'Convention', 'Outspoken', 'Yearling', 'Deputy', 'Civic Duty', 
                            'Reviewer', 'Strunk & White', 'Archaeologist', 'Sportsmanship', 
                            'Research Assistant', 'Taxonomist', 'Booster' )
                   then 'Silver'
              when Name in ('Altruist', 'Benefactor', 'Curious', 'Investor', 
                            'Nice Question', 'Popular Question', 'Promoter', 
                            'Scholar', 'Student', 'Tumbleweed', 'Explainer', 
                            'Nice Answer', 'Revival', 'Self-Learner', 'Teacher', 
                            'Autobiographer', 'Caucus', 'Commentator', 'Mortarboard', 
                            'Precognitive', 'Quorum', 'Talkative', 'Citizen Patrol', 
                            'Cleanup', 'Critic', 'Custodian', 'Disciplined', 
                            'Editor', 'Excavator', 'Organizer', 'Peer Pressure', 
                            'Proofreader', 'Suffrage', 'Supporter', 'Synonymizer', 
                            'Tag Editor', 'Vox Populi', 'Analytical', 'Announcer', 'Informed')
                   then 'Bronze'
              else 'Unknown'
         end as Type,
         1 as Requires
  from Badges

), BadgeSource as (

    -- Regular badges are easy, they all count for themselves.
    -- force Requires to 1

    select Name, Type as Metal, 'Regular' as Source, 1 as Requires
    from BadgeClass
    where Type <> 'Tag'

  Union All

    -- if you have 1 or more tag badge, you have the bronze

    select Name, 'Bronze' as Metal, 'Tag' as Source, 1 as Requires
    from BadgeClass
    where Type = 'Tag'

  Union All

    -- if you have 2 or more tag badge, you have the silver

    select Name, 'Silver' as Metal, 'Tag' as Source, 2 as Requires
    from BadgeClass
    where Type = 'Tag'

  Union All

    -- if you have 3 (cannot have more), you have the gold

    select Name, 'Gold' as  Metal, 'Tag' as Source, 3 as Requires
    from BadgeClass
    where Type = 'Tag'

), UserBadgeSource as (

  -- Count each badge by name, awarded to each user.

  select UserId,
         Name,
         Count (*) as BadgeCount
  from Badges
  group by UserId, Name

), UserBadges as (

  -- Use the Requires column to group the tags to the
  -- users data. Note that if a tag-badge has a count of 3
  -- it will join with all the tag rows in the BadgeSource CTE
  -- thus providing bronze, silver, and gold versions.

  select UserBadgeSource.UserId,
         UserBadgeSource.Name,
         BadgeSource.Metal,
         BadgeSource.Source,
         case when BadgeSource.Source = 'Tag'
              then 1
              else BadgeCount
         end as Quantity
  from UserBadgeSource
  inner join BadgeSource
         on UserBadgeSource.Name = BadgeSource.Name
        and BadgeCount >= BadgeSource.Requires
)

select UserId as [User Link],
       DisplayName as [Sort By],
       Reputation as [Reputation],
       sum(case when Metal = 'Gold' then Quantity else 0 end) as Gold,
       sum(case when Metal = 'Silver' then Quantity else 0 end) as Silver,
       sum(case when Metal = 'Bronze' then Quantity else 0 end) as Bronze,
       sum(case when Metal = 'Unknown' then Quantity else 0 end) as Unknown,
       sum(case when Source = 'Regular' then Quantity else 0 end) as Regular,
       sum(case when Source = 'Tag' then Quantity else 0 end) as Tag,
       sum(Quantity) as Total
from UserBadges inner join Users on UserId = Id
where Reputation >= ##MinReputation:int?200##
group by UserId, DisplayName, Reputation
having sum(Quantity) >= ##MinBadges:int?5##
```

I am looking for any feedback, especially whether there's a better way to accomplish the basic task of assigning classifiers to each badge, and to tag badges. Of course, general style, performance, and consistency reviews are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Style Points

Okay, first things first. you pretty consistently used `lowercase` throughout. You left a `LOWER()` in `UPPER` at the top of the query that I feel compelled to point out to you.

Other than that, you get style points for consistent, easy to read SQL. I personally would have written it in `SHOUTCASE` but as SQL has no real standards to speak of that is mostly a personal preference.

## Improvements

The `BadgeSource` CTE is doing more work than it needs to. Here is an alternate way to achieve the same using the lookup table.

```
select 
    Badges.Name,
    coalesce(TagLookup.Rank,Badges.Type) as Metal,
    case when Badges.Type = 'Tag' 
         then 'Tag'
         else 'Regular'
    end as Source,
    coalesce(TagLookup.Requires,1) as Requires
from BadgeClass as Badges
left join
(
    select 1 as Requires, 'Bronze' as Rank union all
    select 2 as Requires, 'Silver' as Rank union all
    select 3 as Requires, 'Gold' as Rank
) as TagLookup
    on Badges.Type = 'Tag'
```

Okay, This is probably easier to understand than my initial approach. This just joins the BadgeClass to a lookup table, if the record is a tag and relies on the fact that because I did not provide a column to join using it will join the entire lookup table to each tag badge record..

The benefit of doing it this way is that you get to avoid all the extra overhead that comes with the multiple `union all`s in the original. That means we end up with a much nicer execution plan, and a much faster query. You can try the [Updated Users and Badges Query Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/258700/users-and-badges?MinReputation=200&MinBadges=5)

## Overall

That's a pretty nice query overall, you wrote clear, consistent, easy to understand SQL. Well done.

Answer (score 3):

Having stewed over this code for a few days, I have decided there are three things I did not like that are significant.

1. Using a distinct set of badge names from the Badges table required multiple scans of the data. Processing that data with a set of in statements for each badge type was uglier than needed.
2. The multiple stages of case statements to process the data was somewhat overly complicated.
3. The ugly transform (again using case statements), to get the data from row-based to column based could be done better.

### Badge classifications

The first change required transforming the badge source/classification data in a collection of in-statements, to a set of virtual tables instead. Statements like:

> ```
>           when Name in ('Socratic', 'Stellar Question', 'Great Question', 
>                         'Famous Question', 'Illuminator', 'Great Answer', 
>                         'Populist', 'Reversal', 'Unsung Hero', 'Fanatic', 
>                         'Legendary', 'Marshal', 'Constable', 'Sheriff', 
>                         'Steward', 'Copy Editor', 'Electorate', 'Publicist' )
>                then 'Gold'
> ```

become the following instead:

```
select 'Gold' as Metal,
       1 as Requires,
       'Regular' as Source,
       Name as Name
from (values('Socratic'), ('Stellar Question'), ('Great Question'), (
                        'Famous Question'), ('Illuminator'), ('Great Answer'), (
                        'Populist'), ('Reversal'), ('Unsung Hero'), ('Fanatic'), (
                        'Legendary'), ('Marshal'), ('Constable'), ('Sheriff'), (
                        'Steward'), ('Copy Editor'), ('Electorate'), ('Publicist')) Badge(Name)
```

Note that there is no actual table there needed to get the badge source, metal, and name. It is all virtual.

Additionally, the data is all stored in columns. This is convenient for the next stage.

### Reduced manipulations and case statements

The second phase of the operation combines the user badge data, with the above rankings.

Regular and Tag badges need to be handled slightly differently. There's no way to avoid that, but the classification of the badges is simplified significantly by processing data in categorized rows, instead of in columns. Let me explain: the report requires that each badge is accounted for in 3 groupings, the badge source (regular or tag), the metal (bronze, silver, gold), and then finally in a total badge count. Instead of fussing with copying data between columns based on case statements, it is actually easier to just select the data three different ways, and create different rows for each group.

```
    select UserId,
           Source,
           sum(case when Source = 'Tag' then 1 else Quantity end) as Quantity
    from   UserData inner join BadgeClass
        on UserData.Name = BadgeClass.Name and UserData.Quantity >= BadgeClass.Requires
    group by UserId, Source

UNION ALL

    select UserId,
           Metal,
           sum(case when Source = 'Tag' then 1 else Quantity end) as Quantity
    from   UserData inner join BadgeClass
        on UserData.Name = BadgeClass.Name and UserData.Quantity >= BadgeClass.Requires
    group by UserId, Metal

UNION ALL

    select UserId,
           'Total',
           sum(Quantity) as Quantity
    from   UserData
    group by UserId
```

Note how there is now one select for each classification (source, metal, total).

### Pivot

Having simplified the data this way, the target result then becomes a case of a 'simple' pivot, to get the row-organized data in to columns:

```
select *
from DataRows
pivot (sum(Quantity) for Source in ([Total], [Gold], [Silver], [Bronze], [Tag], [Regular])) as PData
```

### Conclusion

The net result of the query is a reduction from:

- 4 CTE's to three
- from multiple scans of the Badges table to just one
- three large in-statement conditions to none (plus a virtual table)
- 7 case statements to just 2.

The final result is available [on SEDE Here (MkII)](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/259587/users-and-badges-mkii?MinReputation=500&MinBadgeCount=5)

The code looks like:

```
-- Find and classify all badge awards for people
-- display summary of gold/silver/bronze awards, and also
-- for tag, or regular badges.
-- Results can be large, so limit it by users with a configurable
-- minimum number of badges.

with BadgeClass as (

    select 'Gold' as Metal,
           1 as Requires,
           'Regular' as Source,
           Name as Name
    from (values('Socratic'), ('Stellar Question'), ('Great Question'), (
                            'Famous Question'), ('Illuminator'), ('Great Answer'), (
                            'Populist'), ('Reversal'), ('Unsung Hero'), ('Fanatic'), (
                            'Legendary'), ('Marshal'), ('Constable'), ('Sheriff'), (
                            'Steward'), ('Copy Editor'), ('Electorate'), ('Publicist')) Badge(Name) 
UNION ALL

    select 'Silver' as Metal,
           1 as Requires,
           'Regular' as Source,
           Name as Name
    from (values('Inquisitive'), ('Favorite Question'), ('Good Question'), (
                            'Notable Question'), ('Enlightened'), ('Refiner'), ('Generalist'), (
                            'Guru'), ('Good Answer'), ('Necromancer'), ('Tenacious'), (
                            'Constituent'), ('Pundit'), ('Enthusiast'), ('Epic'), ('Beta'), (
                            'Convention'), ('Outspoken'), ('Yearling'), ('Deputy'), ('Civic Duty'), (
                            'Reviewer'), ('Strunk & White'), ('Archaeologist'), ('Sportsmanship'), (
                            'Research Assistant'), ('Taxonomist'), ('Booster')) Badge(Name)

UNION ALL

    select 'Bronze' as Metal,
           1 as Requires,
           'Regular' as Source,
           Name as Name
    from (values('Altruist'), ('Benefactor'), ('Curious'), ('Investor'), (
                            'Nice Question'), ('Popular Question'), ('Promoter'), (
                            'Scholar'), ('Student'), ('Tumbleweed'), ('Explainer'), (
                            'Nice Answer'), ('Revival'), ('Self-Learner'), ('Teacher'), (
                            'Autobiographer'), ('Caucus'), ('Commentator'), ('Mortarboard'), (
                            'Precognitive'), ('Quorum'), ('Talkative'), ('Citizen Patrol'), (
                            'Cleanup'), ('Critic'), ('Custodian'), ('Disciplined'), (
                            'Editor'), ('Excavator'), ('Organizer'), ('Peer Pressure'), (
                            'Proofreader'), ('Suffrage'), ('Supporter'), ('Synonymizer'), (
                            'Tag Editor'), ('Vox Populi'), ('Analytical'), ('Announcer'), ('Informed')) Badge(Name)

UNION ALL

    select Metal,
           Requires,
           'Tag' as Source,
           TagName as Name
    from Tags inner join (VALUES('Gold', 3),('Silver',2),('Bronze',1)) Catg(Metal,Requires) on 1 = 1

), UserData as (

    select UserId,
           Name,
           count(*) as Quantity
    from Badges
    group by UserId, Name

), DataRows as (

    select UserId,
           Source,
           sum(case when Source = 'Tag' then 1 else Quantity end) as Quantity
    from   UserData inner join BadgeClass
        on UserData.Name = BadgeClass.Name and UserData.Quantity >= BadgeClass.Requires
    group by UserId, Source

UNION ALL

    select UserId,
           Metal,
           sum(case when Source = 'Tag' then 1 else Quantity end) as Quantity
    from   UserData inner join BadgeClass
        on UserData.Name = BadgeClass.Name and UserData.Quantity >= BadgeClass.Requires
    group by UserId, Metal

UNION ALL

    select UserId,
           'Total',
           sum(Quantity) as Quantity
    from   UserData
    group by UserId

), UserPivot as (

    select *
    from DataRows
    pivot (sum(Quantity) for Source in ([Total], [Gold], [Silver], [Bronze], [Tag], [Regular])) as PData

)

select UserId, DisplayName, Reputation, Total, Gold, Silver, Bronze, Tag, Regular
from UserPivot inner join Users on UserId = Id
where Users.Reputation >=  ##MinReputation:int?500##
  and UserPivot.Total >= ##MinBadgeCount:int?5##
order by Total desc
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN … ON 1=1` is a Cartesian product, better written as [`CROSS JOIN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx).